# creating a delay until a certain number of messages have been received

Tags: java, sockets, delay

I am using socket protocol to send messages between a server program and some client programs

I wish to add code to the server program such that it waits until it has received a certain number of messages (namely, one from each client) before it proceeds

How do I code this?

some client code:-

```
 String message_string = Integer.toString(message_code);

 // send details of prospective trade to the Server
 try {
     InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
     Socket socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), 7001);
     ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
     outputStream.writeObject(name + " " + message_string);
     ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
     String message = (String) inputStream.readObject();
     myConsole.getOut().println("Message: " + message);
     inputStream.close();
     outputStream.close();
 } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
// now wait until the list of optimized trades is received back from the Server
```

I can see the various clients' messages arriving at the server.

Once the number of messages reaches a certain number (i.e. no. of clients) I wish the server code to continue BUT if not I wish the server to 'wait'

Comment: What code do you currently have?

Comment: being a programmer you should be able to decide some logic. You are not presenting any logic of your own.

Comment: Please take the time and do **proper** formatting of the code you are posting.

Comment: Just read one message from each client in turn. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: to code the server so that it knows when all client messages have been received and therefore it can continue with the remaining server code

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear

The server receives a prospective trade from each client

Once all prospective trades are in, the server does some calculations and then returns the list of optimized trades to all clients

So, I actually have two 'wait' periods required

One with the server, and one with each client